next js dynamic routing errorUnhandled Runtime Error
enter image description here
Problem Details
I encountered an error while using a Next.js application with TypeScript. Specifically, I created a component AboutPage that takes a prop named para, which contains an aboutId string. When I tried to render this component, I received the following runtime error:
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Check para is defined. Use:
const AboutPage = ({ para }: { para: { aboutId: string } }) => {
  if (!para) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  return <h1>About details: {para.aboutId}</h1>;
};
export default AboutPage;

Fetch data in getServerSideProps:
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

const AboutPage = ({ para }: { para: { aboutId: string } }) => {
  if (!para) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  return <h1>About details: {para.aboutId}</h1>;
};

export default AboutPage;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { aboutId } = context.params;
  const para = { aboutId };
  return { props: { para } };
};

Fix error. para needed.
